# Is it possible to use the provided Java Collections methods, like max, min, sort, ect..., on a Stack?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, stack

I was working on a problem involving Stacks on HackerRank ([See Here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/maximum-element/problem)). One of the parts of the question asked to provide the max value within the Stack. I thought an easy way to do this was to just write an extended Stack class with a max() method (see below). That worked but I thought an even easier way might be to just take advantage of Java's Collections methods. So I built the craftyMax() method (also seen below).

```
class MyStack<T> extends Stack<T> {
    public T craftyMax() {
        return Collections.max(this);
    }

    public T max() {
        Integer max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        for (T item: this) {
            max = Math.max((Integer)item, max);
        }

        return (T) max;
    }
}
```

Of course this did not work as the compiler replied with:

```
Solution.java:6: error: no suitable method found for max(MyStack<T#1>)
        return Collections.max(this);
                          ^
    method Collections.<T#2>max(Collection<? extends T#2>) is not applicable
      (inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
        inferred: T#1
        upper bound(s): Comparable<? super T#1>,Object)
    method Collections.<T#3>max(Collection<? extends T#3>,Comparator<? super T#3>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#3
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
  where T#1,T#2,T#3 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in class MyStack
    T#2 extends Object,Comparable<? super T#2> declared in method <T#2>max(Collection<? extends T#2>)
    T#3 extends Object declared in method <T#3>max(Collection<? extends T#3>,Comparator<? super T#3>)
Note: Solution.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
```

Since, I have tried a few different things and been looking around but I can't seem to find if what I am trying to do here is possible or not. So my question is:

Is it possible to use the provided Java Collections methods, like max, min, sort, ect..., on / within a Stack? Or am I expecting a little too much?

Comment: `Collections#max` certainly works on a stack.  I think the real question here is that your custom code is broken, and you want help with that.  Maybe you should edit your question.

Comment: Why would you do max on a Stack? Think of a real world stack where you would need to pop every element and check for max till now O(N) space and O(N) time complexity? You could do it in O(1) by adding max element till now as a field in object that you are storing. Also don't use Stack as it's all methods are expensive from threading perspective and even if you are using stack in one thread its expensive.

Comment: @SMA thank you for the info. I do understand that the best approach is to store the max value as items are added to provide O(1) on retrieval of the max vs O(n). However, that is not my question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen like SMA mentioned the max function is not ideal and therefore not really the point. I prefer the O(1) solution but I am only using the code provided as an example. If you're aware of any examples or documentation to my actual question please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection<? extends T> coll)
```

only works for `Collection`s whose element type implements the `Comparable` interface.

Therefore, your code will work with the proper type bound:

```
class MyStack<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Stack<T> {
    public T craftyMax() {
        return Collections.max(this);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure about your second method (`max()`), though. You are casting `T` to `Integer`. If you are certain `T` is an `Integer`, why not define `MyStack` as `class MyStack extends Stack<Integer>`?

Answer (score 0):

You can only call `Collections.max` with a single argument on types that implement the `Comparable` interface. Change your type declaration to

```
class MyStack<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Stack<T> {
```

and it should work. Or, as an alternative, you can take the two-argument max that takes a `Comparator` as the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

you can override the comparator to match your functionality like below.

```
if (!MyStack.isEmpty()) {
Integer max = Collections.min(MyStack, new Comparator<Integer>() {
@Override
public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
  return o2.compareTo(o1);
}
});
}
```